# How to stop Rails 4.0.1 installing when installing cucumber rails training wheels

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber, ubuntu-12.04

I am working on a Ubuntu 12.04 setup for a course that needs to have cucumber rails training wheels installed on it.

I am working with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.x.

After installing Ruby and doing gem install rails -v 3.2.14 or .15 I install cucumber with

```
gem install cucumber -v **tried various versions**
gem install cucumber-rails -v **tried various versions**
gem install cucumber-rails-training-wheels
```

Everything works fine except that every time I run the last command it also changes the Rails version to 4.0.1

I do not want Rails 4.0.1 installed at all for this.

Here is the list of gems installed prior to this on one of the many tries and the results of the above command.

```
gem list
actionmailer (3.2.15)
actionpack (3.2.15)
activemodel (3.2.15)
activerecord (3.2.15)
activeresource (3.2.15)
activesupport (3.2.15)
arel (3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.3)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capybara (2.1.0)
cucumber (1.3.8)
cucumber-rails (1.3.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
gherkin (2.12.2)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.5)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.8.1)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25)
mini_portile (0.5.2)
minitest (4.7.0)
multi_json (1.8.2)
multi_test (0.0.2)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.15)
railties (3.2.15)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sprockets (2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.8)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
xpath (2.0.0)

gem install cucumber-rails-training-wheels
Successfully installed cucumber-rails-training-wheels-1.0.0
Successfully installed activesupport-4.0.1
Successfully installed rack-1.5.2
Successfully installed actionpack-4.0.1
Successfully installed activemodel-4.0.1
Successfully installed arel-4.0.1
Successfully installed activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3
Successfully installed activerecord-4.0.1
Successfully installed actionmailer-4.0.1
Successfully installed railties-4.0.1
Successfully installed sprockets-2.10.0
Successfully installed sprockets-rails-2.0.1
12 gems installed
```

Update: I was working off a script that had it done this way. But after thinking about it more, I'm thinking that I don't really need to install it this way and can just leave it out of the initial VM setup script and just include it in Gemfile as necessary. When being added through bundle install I suspect I won't have the same issue. It would still be interesting to know if this is possible as well as why it does this. I would have expected it not to install Rails since a greater version of Rails then it's dependency was already installed. Maybe this is not the way it works and if not, a post or link to some good information on how the gem dependencies work would be appreciated. Thank you.

Update2: I was correct. It works fine when just included in Gemfile and does not need to be in the setup script.

Comment: how u r checking rails version?

Comment: Before doing gem install cucumber-rails-training-wheels, typing rails -v will show 3.2.x. After install rails -v will show 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It installs rails 4.0.1 because cucumber-rails-training-wheels gem depends on rails (every rails version higher than 3.1). Take a look at: 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails-training-wheels/blob/master/cucumber-rails-training-wheels.gemspec

So it installs latest rails, thus, rails 4.0.1.

Comment: It shows s.add_development_dependency('rails', '>= 3.1.0') so I would think that means that it needs a version of rails greater than or equal to 3.1.0. Since 3.2.x is already installed, that should satisfy the dependency and it should not install 4.0.1. Maybe this is not the way it works although this is what seems most reasonable to me.

Comment: Marked as accepted answer as it is the only answer and is apparently correct although it is unclear why.